# Unicode text to Arabic Text in Excel

Tags: excel, function, unicode, arabic

I have asked here to how put `%u` after every four digit to convert my long string into a proper unicode text. I got a very nice reply with the UDF and it work great.. now from this string

```
002006390632064A0632064A00200627064406390645064A0644003A0020062A0645002006270644
```

I am able to convert it into

```
%u0020%u0639%u0632%u064A%u0632%u064A%u0020%u0627%u0644%u0639%u0645%u064A%u0644%u003A%u0020%u062A%u0645%u0020%u0627%u0644
```

Well the string is to long i just showed you the result... Now what I am looking is there any excel function which can convert this into Arabic text. Actually its a uncode and want to see how it look in Arabic. 
Currently I am using a website

> http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

to convert it manually. Is there any excel function which can do that locally.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a byte array from the code and assigning this byte array to a String. This String can then be assigned to a Cell.

Example:

```
Sub test()

 Dim sCode As String

 sCode = "002006390632064A0632064A00200627064406390645064A0644003A0020062A0645002006270644"

 Dim b() As Byte
 Dim j As Long
 j = 0

 For i = 1 To Len(sCode) Step 4

  ReDim Preserve b(j + 1)
  b(j) = Val("&H" & Mid(sCode, i + 2, 2))
  b(j + 1) = Val("&H" & Mid(sCode, i, 2))
  j = j + 2

 Next

 Dim s As String
 s = b

 Range("A1").Value = s

End Sub
```

Comment: i need to convert the unicode string of  %u0020%u0639%u0632%u064A%u0632%u064A%u0020%u0627%u0644%u0639%u0645%u064A%u0644%u003A%u0020%u062A%u0645%u0020%u0627%u0644 to  عزيزي العميل: تم ال. in excel is that possible

Comment: So using my code, which uses the code String without the "%u", you simply must overstep the "%u". It should be possible for you to change the code, shouldn't it?